# Typeahead.js Bloodhound - Object has no method split

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bloodhound

I'm trying to make Bloodhound work.

The code I have:

```
var licenses = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function(d) {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        local: [{ "value": 1 , "text": "A"}, { "value": 2 , "text": "C+E"}]
    });

licenses.initialize();
```

throws an error

> Object 1 has no method 'split'

What's wrong in this code?

Comment: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/740

Comment: I saw that, but I need value/text combination, to be able to display and save different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a number as search term you must convert it as string like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var numbers;

    numbers = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function (d) {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value.toString());
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        local: [{ "value": 1 , "text": "A"}, { "value": 2 , "text": "C+E"}]
    });

    numbers.initialize();

    $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        displayKey: 'value',
        source: numbers.ttAdapter()
    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/6HSMA/